# Android - how to make horizontal buttons have no space between them?

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now I have these buttons that line up nicely, but they have some space between them.
To look like a more professional header, I would like to not have space between the buttons.  Is that possible?

Here is my current layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
>


 <Button android:id="@+id/home"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Home"
  android:textSize="11dp"
/>

<Button android:id="@+id/questions"
 android:layout_width="0dp" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Questions"
 android:textSize="11dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"  />  


 <Button android:id="@+id/businesses"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:textSize="11dp"
  android:text="Businesses"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/questions"
 />  

 <Button android:id="@+id/learn"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Learn"
  android:textSize="11dp"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/businesses"
 />  

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to change the images for the buttons. The default buttons that you are using, those backgrounds have some padding around them. that's why you see the space between them.

Since, you have a different use-case for the Buttons, you will need new images for them.